# How to use PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to use Android's PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting that has been available since API 1.0

Trouble is, I don't understand how to use it correctly.  I pass a string with the path of the package component but the the environment states the error:

```
The method setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName, int, int) in the type PackageManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int)
```

What is the ComponentName and how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the ComponentName

[`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) is made up of the package name of the app and the class name of the component.

> how do I find it?

Since it is your app, you know your app's package (e.g., `getPackageName()` on your `Context`). Since it is your component, you know your component's class name. From there, just call the appropriate constructor.

Comment: I want to disable/hide other app , may i disable other app using this method.

Comment: @Hardik: No, sorry, you do not have the rights to disable components of other apps.

Comment: is it possible to enable, disable a sendBroadcast() that is used to speak text?